# display:flex; cancels margins% on firefox but works on chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, portability

I'm using Bootstrap and wanted to vertically center **div class="col-md-12"** in a **div class="row"**.

So I added this class to my **div class="row"**:

```
.row-vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

However, my **div class="col-md-12"** have margins in %, working on Chrome, but not on Mozilla.

If i remove the display:flex;, the margins come back but here goes my vertical alignment.

Could you please help me find a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: table;` to parent class (row) and `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;` to child class (col-md-12).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to work. I removed my custom class and added the properties you mentioned but the divs aren't vertically aligned.

Comment: Top/bottom don't work, however left/right work just fine.